# Finding Max and Min Values from a Symmetric Data Frame - Pandas/Python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe, say:

```
  a b c d e 
a 1 2 3 5 2
b 2 1 3 4 3
c 2 4 1 5 6
d 1 5 6 1 1
e 2 3 4 1 1
```

(1) I need to find MAX and MIN values other than the indicies (i,i). For this example: I need to get the solution as Max: 6, occurs 2 times at (c,e), (d,c). Similarly for MIN value too. How do I do this using Pandas/Python?

(2) Similarly, if a specify a row (or a column) I need to get its MAX and MIN vals other than the ROW index (or Col index). SO, if I specify row a, I need to get MAX val as 5 and occurs at (a,b), (a,e). Thanks.

Comment: As you can't add links to images your last edits are pointless, also it's preferable to post text that is copy-pastable rather than images

Comment: Why do you call your dataframe symmetric?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your diagonal to null and then take the max or min value along either axis.

For example:

```
df_copy = df.copy().astype('float')

for i in range(len(df_copy)): 
    df_copy.iat[i, i] = np.nan

>>> df_copy
    a   b   c   d   e
a NaN   2   3   5   2
b   2 NaN   3   4   3
c   2   4 NaN   5   6
d   1   5   6 NaN   1
e   2   3   4   1 NaN

>>> df_copy.max(axis=1)  # Rows.
a    5
b    4
c    6
d    6
e    4
dtype: float64

>>> df_copy.max(axis=0)  # Columns.
a    2
b    5
c    6
d    5
e    6
dtype: float64
```

Given that you index equals your columns and both are sorted in the same order, you can get the column/index values of max/min values as follows:

```
>>> [df.index.get_loc(k) for k in df_copy.idxmax(axis=1)]  # Rows.
[3, 3, 4, 2, 2]

>>> [df.index.get_loc(k) for k in df_copy.idxmax(axis=0)]  # Columns.
[1, 3, 3, 0, 2]
```

Note that you can have multiple values equal the the maximum (as with this example), but that `idxmax` will only return the first.

Comment: Many thanks, Mr. Alexander. Any suggestion for other parts? -  for freqency of occurrences  and extracting the corresponding coordinates for the max and min values.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The get_loc returns integer index. I am looking for string index. I can map it back I guess.

Comment: Hah!  It took me a bit to figure out the integer indexing.  The string indexing is easy.  `df_copy.idxmax(axis=...)`